# Is it possible to load an external website inside a Cordova mobile app on Windows?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-cordova

I have created the default Cordova application using

```
cordova create ...
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add windows
```

In the index.html, I added some links to an external websites (not locally installed html files):

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">External Website</a>
<a href="http://dev2.prsx.net">External Intranet Site</a>
```

In Android, tapping these links pulls up the site within the Cordova container. This is the behavior I want. On Windows, it pulls up the example.com page in the external Internet Explorer browser. Nothing happens when I click on the dev2.prsx.net link. Literally, nothing happens. It doesn't open a browser, it doesn't change the screen in any way, there is no error message in Visual Studio.

It should be noted that I want to load the intranet site in the Cordova container because the external site will also include the cordova.js file and plugins that I will use. This works on Android. But right now, I just want to know if I can load external pages on Windows.

Is it possible to replicate the behavior seen in Android on the Windows platform?

Edit:
I went in to the package.windows.appxmanifest file and looked at the Capabilities tab. I turned on the Private Networks Capability and now my intranet site does load in the external IE browser. So now my only question is, can I make the site load in the Cordova container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have found that works is by creating an iFrame or x-ms-webview to load the remote content in. This is essentially what InAppBrowser does for you. However, my problem was that I want the remote content to be able to call Cordova APIs. To accomplish this, I use pass messages back and forth between the webview and the parent local page that has access to APIs. I do this with the MSWebViewScriptNotify event on the webview and the invokeScriptAsync method as described in this article: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/10/01/blending-apps-and-sites-with-the-html-x-ms-webview/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) to open web page like var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

Comment: According to the documentation for InAppBrowser, the _blank target loads the page in the InAppBrowser, and not in the Cordova View. This means that the webpage that is loaded doesn't have access to the Cordova API.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in a click event and before that install InAppBrowser in your app

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');

This will exactly like you want